# Mandatory to perform a CAST to a specific datatype to apply criteria to a sql_variant column in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table with columns like so:

```
KeyName varchar(50)  
RowNumber int  
LocationValue sql_variant  


select * from myTable where LocationValue = 'some string' -- no results, but no error
select * from myTable where CAST(LocationValue AS VARCHAR) = 'some string' --works
```

If LocationValue can contain either numeric or string data, is it **mandatory** to CAST that column to NUMERIC or VARCHAR in order to apply criteria to it?

Not doing so doesn't cause any error, however no results are returned.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071.aspx) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't mandatory as such, but you need to CAST it to a meaningful type for that comparison: if only for maintainability and your sanity.

The rules for conversions are here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071.aspx). Above that, you have things on collation and SET ANSI_PADDING that will all affect results. An explicit CAST overrides these rules.

I can't actually say why you see this because I haven't used sql_variant for years but I refer you to my first statement about "sanity"

Comment: Marked as correct, although I think it **is** mandatory, but even if it isn't, I think its good practice to do so.